# Fluent Mapping ou Data Annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Estava a assistir uma vídeo aula sobre ASP.NET MVC, quando vejo o *Fluent Mapping* do Entity Framework pela primeira vez.

Logo me veio a dúvida.

Qual dos dois é melhor recomendado? *Fluent Mapping* ou *Data Annotations*?

Gostei muito do *Fluent Mapping* pois posso jogar as validações para uma classe separada mantendo minha classe limpa, porém o *Data Annotations* tem o `[Display(Name"")]` que uso muito.

É possível mesclar os dois?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Qual dos dois é melhor recomendado? *Fluent Mapping* ou *Data Annotations*?

Não existe "melhor recomendado" aqui. Eles são complementares, possuindo várias funções em comum. Cada um é usado de acordo com sua necessidade.

A decoração por atributos (que você chamou *Data Annotations*, que é na verdade [o nome do *namespace* dos atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168377/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-data-annotations-e-fluent-api/186770#186770)) é mais sucinta e orientada à apresentação, enquanto que a *Fluent API* funciona muito bem para configurações globais do banco de dados, sendo mais prolixa e menos legível quanto a configuração de entidades e propriedades de entidades.

Neste caso, a *Fluent API* também usa [o *namespace* `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168377/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-data-annotations-e-fluent-api/186770#186770).

Entretanto, a *Fluent API* possui funcionalidades a mais que a decoração por atributos. [Falo sobre elas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168377/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-data-annotations-e-fluent-api/186770#186770).

> É possível mesclar os dois?

Sim, é possível, e até normal, visto que alguns recursos são exclusivos de um ou de outro.

> Gostei muito do *Fluent Mapping* pois posso jogar as validações para uma classe separada mantendo minha classe limpa, porém o *Data Annotations* tem o `[Display(Name"")]` que uso muito.

Qual a vantagem de "manter a classe limpa"? O usuário do seu sistema não vê a classe. Empatia **nunca** deve ser um critério para usar um *framework* em detrimento de outro.

[`[Display]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) não é usada pela *Fluent API* porque não enuncia um comportamento de banco de dados: enuncia um comportamento de apresentação.