# Qual a diferença entre Data Annotations e Fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, terminologia, code-first, dataannotations, fluent-api

Qual a diferença entre Data Annotations e Fluent API?

Há alguma restrição entre uma ou outra? Melhorar na performance ou são apenas duas formas de fazer a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Qual a diferença entre Data Annotations e Fluent API?

A abordagem, principalmente, mas há um problema conceitual na sua pergunta, porque a Fluent API faz uso do *namespace* [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) quando o programador enuncia as regras de composição do domínio de dados. Ou seja, as duas não são comparáveis, a rigor.

A pergunta seria algo como "qual a diferença entre a Fluent API e o modelo por decoração usando atributos?" (aí sim, falando de *Data Annotations*).

Ainda falando sobre a abordagem, temos que a decoração por atributos atua sobre classes que representam *Models* e suas propriedades, enquanto que a Fluent API atua num nível mais global, enunciando regras diretamente no contexto de dados da aplicação.

> Há alguma restrição entre uma ou outra? Melhorar na performance ou são apenas duas formas de fazer a mesma coisa?

Ao usar ambos os recursos, recomenda-se não expressar as mesmas regras duas vezes, pois isso pode confundir o Entity Framework e causar erros. Acho que isso seria o mais próximo de restrição no uso de ambas.

A Fluent API é considerando um recurso mais avançado, com alguns recursos a mais, já que [a própria Microsoft admite que não é possível expressar todo tipo de configuração apenas com decoração por atributos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx). Alguns exemplos:

- Desligar exclusão em cascata:

  ```
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
  ```
- Associação N para N sem explicitar um *Model* definindo a associação (não muito recomendado):

  ```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>() 
              .HasMany(p => p.Lojas) 
              .WithMany(l => l.Produtos) 
              .Map(m => 
              { 
                  m.ToTable("ProdutosLojas"); 
                  m.MapLeftKey("ProdutoId"); 
                  m.MapRightKey("LojaId"); 
              });
  ```
- Especificar chave estrangeira se não é desejável usar uma propriedade no *Model* para isso (não muito recomendado, mas dá pra fazer):

  ```
  .Map(conf => conf.MapKey("ChaveEstrangeiraId"))
  ```
- Ajuste fino do banco de dados, especialmente nos casos em que apenas um lado da associação é exposto no *Model* (o que é problemático, mas pode ser feito):

  ```
  .WithMany(...)
  .WithOptional(...)
  .WithRequiredDependent(...)
  .WithRequiredPrincipal(...)
  ```
- Especificação de herança entre *Model* e banco de dados (Tabela por Hierarquia, Tabela por Tipo, Tabela por Classe Concreta):

  ```
  .Map<TDerivado>(Action<EntityMappingConfiguration<TDerivado>> ...)
  ```

É importante notar que a Fluent API é um recurso mais complexo e mais verboso que a decoração por atributos. Além disso, o uso errado da Fluent API pode causar problemas de coesão. Nada impede de você especificar no seu sistema o conjunto de *Models* totalmente em separado dos mapeamentos.

Se me permite uma recomendação, a Fluent API deve ser usada para os casos em que a decoração de atributos não atende.

Answer (score 3):

O mecanismo de [atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101) sempre foi muito limitado. Ele é resolvido todo em compilação e usado com reflexão, o que impede fazer muita coisa.

Além disto, as anotações disponíveis no Entity Framework são limitadas, dá para fazer o básico, mas não é muito flexível. Nem poderia ser diferente, a sintaxe de atributos não permite muita expressividade.

Um mecanismo que permite uma sintaxe mais livre, permite resolver coisas dinamicamente e que gera um objeto mais complexo tende a ser mais flexível, permitindo realizar o que era impensável com as `dataannotation`s. Lembre-se que estamos comparando uma forma declarativa de [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) com uma forma imperativa de código, não dá para comparar.

Por tudo isto há mais opções disponíveis na API fluente.

Por acaso escolheram que a API tivesse uma sintaxe fluente, até por limitação da sintaxe da linguagem, não precisava ser assim se a linguagem fosse mais poderosa. O que importa é a capacidade de expressar o que deseja.

Eu sempre achei essa forma melhor e nunca entendi porque tanto usaram atributos.

Mas o ASP.NET MVC se beneficia da anotação de dados, então é algo para se pensar. Uma pena ter sido criado assim.

Não fiz teste e não posso ter certeza, intuitivamente acredito que a API fluente é mais rápida por ser um mecanismo específico e mais concreto que o atributo que é um mecanismo abstrato e geral demais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando você se refere a _atributos_ você se refere a `Data Annotations`, certo!

Comment: Exato, ele tem limitações que impõe ao uso específico mais limitações

Answer (score 0):

Usando Data Annotations você cria um certo acoplamento em deixar uma entidade acoplada a uma tecnologia.

Fluent API você consegue separar a responsabilidade que antes era acoplada na camada de domínio em outra camada. Exemplo: faço o mapeamento do Fluent API na camada de acesso a dados (DAL) isolando a camada de domínio.

Em termos de performance acredito que não tenha mudança, mas ambas fazem mesma coisa eu costumo usar sempre Fluent API.

Comment: O *namespace* `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` não é "acoplado a uma tecnologia": ele é agnóstico. Além disso, não há qualquer vantagem em "isolar a camada de domínio" no Entity Framework porque ele trabalha muito próximo ao domínio.